# installing ubuntu on acer laptop without hard drive

Tags: partitioning

My Acer laptop kept rebooting, not allowing me to even access the bios. so i took out the hard drive and that solved the problem.I then put ubuntu on a flash drive and proceeded to install it.I got to the screen where it says installation type.It only gives me the option of /dev/sda when i click on install now it says no root file systom is defined, and it wont let me click on the option of a new partition table, or to change or anything. i dont know if its my computer or im just doing something wrong. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Acer notebooks are notorious on that front. It won't let you boot from usb unless there is no other bootable drive attached. The only way to change this is by special software tool by acer, but your system is not booting properly, so... Quick & dirty fix: connect the hdd to another system and use a tool like GPartEd to remove the bootable flag. Then put it back in your laptop and boot from USB stick to install. Make appropriate **backup** of your data before attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a spot to install the system. A flash drive only works as a temp system. Loads itself into memory when using and as memory is volatile when you shut down it is wiped. Sounds like your hard drive has failed.